# Constraint Labels Next To Each Other

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode, constraints

I am trying to constraints two labels that are next to each other on the storyboard, however, it is not working. Any help on how to successfully constraints two labels next to each other, without them interfering with each other would be great.

When the labels are constrained without issues the app crashes, clearly because the constraints are impeding with each other.

Issues that I receive are below:

```
'Frame for UIImage will be different at run time'
'Horizontal position will be 139 at run time but is 56 in the canvas'
'Width will be 27 at run time but is 110 in the canvas'
```

I believe the issue is that when the score label is constrained, and it increases by any number, the label size changes, hence causing the storyboard to refresh, and therefore all animations disappear and cease like when the app is first started up. I have tried to make the label bigger so that when the font size changes it doesn't affect the storyboard, however this is not working.

Thanks.

Comment: Please show your UI & constraints

Answer (score 0):

**Follow these steps:** 
1- Keep both of your button side by side and make gap as much you want. 
2-Now select both Button and add constraints from left ,right , and top. and make that the second button constraints should be ion relative to first constraints.

Comment: Creating using the storyboard. So yes, auto layout.

Comment: ok, Follow these steps:
1- Keep both of your button side by side and make gap as much you want.
2-Now select both Button and add constraints from left ,right , and top. and make that the second button constraints should be ion relative to first constraints.

Comment: There labels, instead of buttons, however this should not matter correct?

Comment: no this should not matter...just follow the steps of autolayout as i have told

Comment: I have followed your steps. However, the labels do not remain in their position.

Comment: have you given the contraints of height and width as well?? if not plz add it

Comment: and let me know what issue you are facing in following mu steps

Comment: The labels now hold in their correct positions. However now, when my animations collide, the score adds up correctly, however it ceases the animation and nothing happens. It seems whenever the labels are constrained, the animations collide once and cease movement.

Comment: if you want to change the position of the label using animation then you have  to change the constraints programatically else it will hold the position as it is.

Comment: I'm not animating the label. I have other animations ongoing, however now when they collide, the game glitches and they all cease. This is not the case when the labels are not constrained.

Comment: i'm not getting your issue

Answer (score 0):

Please share some code. If you want two labels constrained next to each other, the first label will need to be pinned to the left of its superview and have either a top/bottom constraint to the superview or a fixed height. The second label should have a constraint from its left margin to the right margin of the first label. Your second label will also need a right constraint pinned to the right of the superview, and a top/bottom or fixed height as well.

Comment: I have followed your steps, and the labels hold in their corrected positions. However, now that I have constrained both labels correctly, the other animations in my app cease. When animations collide in my app, the score is instructed to increase. When the labels are constrained (like they are now), and my animations collide my animations glitch out and stop. However, when I have constraints placed on either label the animations collide and add up the score successfully. The animations only stop when the labels are constrained.

Comment: I have been re-arranging constraints, and now I have found that my animations do not cease, they are moving however, they stop just before the score and high-score labels and reset. I want them to keep going. I am not sure why this is occurring.

Comment: Can you share some code? It's hard to diagnose your problem without seeing anything. What do you mean by your animations collide? Why would your other animations cease? Are you animating by using layoutIfNeeded() inside of an animation block?